# Attempts to post correct Python code fail - sute review demands indents where none should be, Ibdebts fauk ti run

Tags: posting

I tried to post a question about Treeview with minimal code.  The site filter demands that the code be indented and blocks the post.  I've tested multiple indent forms and all fail.  The minimal code contains no flow control or subordinate statements.

Is there a way to override the filter?

Ass stated above, I've tried indents.  All fail.